# drupal 7 terms and conditions in a popup

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a drupal site running, and I have a requirement to add the terms and conditions on the registration page. But the terms and conditions must be displayed in a pop-up box wen the user clicks on the link.

I have tried the "Terms_of_ues" module, but it does not provide much functionality. 
Also tried the "Legal" modules but it does not have an option for popups, it only has scrollbox and link options.

How would I go about displaying the terms and conditions in a popup box?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/npop

Comment: @leymannx I tried npop, created an anchor like this: 
<a href="#" class="use-ajax" data-npop="355">Open Dialog</a>

But still doesnt show the popup

Comment: Then debug. What does happen instead? An error or something? On the console anything? Did you clear Drupal and browser cache properly?

Comment: No errors in browser console. Cleared caches and checked again but nothing. Tried to use the npop_create_link() function, same , no errors no popup.

Comment: Seems you need to file a bug on https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/npop. You still could try `Variant 2: Set href attribute as "ajax/npop/node/[nid]/load/nojs", where [nid] nid of node and set link class "use-ajax".`